# jQuery: dynamically updating a list of N latest values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple function that will update a page with data pushed from the server. For the sake of simplicity, I am using a timer to simulate the server push.

Each time a server message is pushed, I want to update the list shown on the page, with the newly received message placed at the top of the list, and the earliest one being dropped of the list.

This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main_cntr">
            <ul id="lst">
                <li>Line 1 ....</li>
                <li>Line 2 ....</li>
                <li>Line 3 ....</li>
                <li>Line 4 ....</li>
                <li>Line 5 ....</li>
            </ul>
        <div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         // mimics server side push message received at front end
         // update list to contain only the last 5 elements
         function update_list(newtext){
            // Fetch li elements in $('#lst')
            // truncate last one
            // insert new text to top of li list (ideally, I want to pass the new text to insert to this function)
            alert('Got called')
         }

         $(document).ready(function() {
            window.setInterval(update_list, 10000);
         });
    </script>
</html>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I implement this correctly (I'm not really a JQuery expert)
2. How do I modify the function `update_list()` so that I can pass it a new text (e.g. random text), so that it better mimics data being pushed by the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example based on your code which removes the last element in the list and adds a new one to the top of the list

```
// mimics server side push message received at front end
// update list to contain only the last 5 elements
function update_list(newtext){
    // Fetch li elements in $('#lst')
    // truncate last one
    $('#lst li').last().remove()

    // insert new text to top of li list (ideally, I want to pass the new text to insert to this function)
    $('#lst').prepend("<li>"+newtext+"</li>");

    alert('Got called')
}
```

Further to this if you wanted to improve your simulation with random data you could do something like this

```
var wordArray = ["hey", "you", "there"];

function RandomWord() {
    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * wordArray.length));
    return wordArray[i];
}
```

Then replace the line in `update_list` to be this

```
$('#lst').prepend("<li>"+RandomWord()+"</li>");
```

Lastly here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LQr7Q/2/) showing the random aspect of this working

Comment: Wouldn't you want to grab the List's children? Something like $('#lst').children().last().remove().end().end().prepend("<li>"+RandomWord+"</li>");

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like you need a little 101 in jQuery.  The internet is filled with resources, and after you read this post, I hope you go and run through a few tutorials on the power of `$`, but for now, we can help with this.

One of the most basic (and common) uses for jQuery is to get DOM elements without having to use the lengthy `document.getElementById("id")`.  With jQuery we can simply say `$("#id")` (note: the pound symbol lets jQuery know it's looking for an object ID, this is important).  Both `getElementById` and `$` return objects, but where `getElementById` returns a DOM element, `$` returns a jQuery object.  In this case we're interested in using the jQuery function [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), a function that has similar functionality to xHTML's append function in DOM elements (support outside of xHTML is janky at best) only where append adds it's arguments as a last child, prepend adds them as a first.

`$().prepend()` is super easy to use.  It adds it's argument after any existing content in it's parent object.  The argument can be a DOM element, a jQuery object, or a string (any string).  In this case, a string will do just fine.

```
function update_list(newtext)
{
    $("#lst").prepend("<li>" + newtext + "</li>");
}
```

This code will make a new jQuery object representing your `<ul>` with id `lst` (remember: pound symbol!) and ask it to prepend a new `<li>` onto it with `newtext` as it's contents.